# Laravel displays redirecting to url

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4, laravel-validation

Hello everyone I'm trying to validate my input but I have weird problem with redirecting when Validation fails laravel displays "Redirecting to http://localhost:8888/public/admin/categories/create" before page load.
Here is my validation in controller:

```
$rules = [
            'name' => 'required | unique:categories'
        ];
        $input = Input::all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::route('admin.categories.create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

How I can delete this message and only display page with errors?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask Laravel to redirect, it does 2 things:

- send a Location header with the target URL - this is the default redirect method
- output HTML with a redirect done using Javascript - this is a fallback mechanism in case header could not be sent

If you're seing the fallback mechanism, it means there were issues sending the header. The most common reason is that your code did output something before redirect header was sent. Enable error reporting (**error_reporting(E_ALL)**) and you will probably get a warning saying "headers already sent".

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL); to app/start/global.php but I don't have any errors message my laravel.log file is empty too. How I can find this error?

Comment: Add ob_start() at the beginning of your global.php and then dd(strlen(ob_get_contents())); right before your "return Redirect". It should output amount of data that has been already echo'ed

Comment: I've got `int 4` only after submitting form. Weird.. any ideas?

Comment: Do dd(ob_get_contents()); to see what was echo'ed - maybe that will help you finding the place that echoes something. Make sure you don't output anything before the redirect and you won't see the HTML when redirecting

Comment: When I have ob_start() at the beginning message doesn't show but when I delete it it shows again. Any idea why?

Comment: Because by using that you're buffering output, so nothing will be sent to the browsers. It's a workaround, not a fix.

Comment: So how can I fix it when the dd(ob_get_contents()); returns only int 4? How can I found problem.

Comment: That's what dd(strlen(ob_get_contents())) was returning - length of the buffer content. Remove the strlen and you'll get buffer content. Finding where it is echoed is something only you can do as you have access to the code.

Comment: But it returns `string ' ' (length=4)` it means there is no buffer?

Comment: No, it means you're outputting 4 white characters like spaces. The reason might be blank lines after closing ?> tags.

Comment: Ok I understand, should I look for it in contrller view or routes? And how can I determine if there are any white characters?

Comment: White characters can be outputed anywhere, in any of your files.

Comment: Is there any way to delete all of them? Btw I don't use ?> at the end of file it may cause errors?

Comment: Ok I have one more question files should have UTF-8 or UTF-8 with BOM encoding?