# Redirection headers is visible instead hidden in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I use **Laravel 8** (the last version), and I want redirect users to Twitter to log them.

*I realized that there was this display also on previous versions of Laravel.*

I use this line code:

```
return redirect()->away($url);
// or
return redirect($url);
```

Why, when I use this lines code to login user with Twitter, I've this display on page between login page and Twitter login page ?

#### My login method in controller

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

public function login(Request $request): string
{
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(
        config('services.twitter.client_id'),
        config('services.twitter.client_secret')
    );

    $requestToken = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', [
        'oauth_callback' => config('services.twitter.redirect'),
    ]);

    $request->session()->put('oauth_token', $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    $request->session()->put('oauth_token_secret', $requestToken['oauth_token_secret']);

    $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', [
        'oauth_token' => $requestToken['oauth_token'],
    ]);

    return redirect()->away($url);
}
```

The redirection is visible, and ugly.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639278/laravel-displays-redirecting-to-url#answer-31639520 ?

Comment: did you return redirect inside controller correctly

Comment: @ChinhNguyễn I've added more code in issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Incorrect return value is declared for your login function, you should change return type `string` to `RedirectResponse` (Alternative, you can remove type declarations altogether)

```
public function login(Request $request): string
```

to:

```
public function login(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
```